# Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp (Error #1139)

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a column `phone_number` on a database that an entry may contain more than one phone number. The plan is to identify entries which do not pass a regex expression validation.

This is the query I am using to accomplish my objective:

```
 SELECT id, phone_number FROM store WHERE phone_number NOT REGEXP '^\s*\(?(020[78]?\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2,3} ?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8][0-9]{3}\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{3})\s*$';
```

Problem is, every time I run the code, I get an error:

`Error Code: 1139. Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you supply some examples? It seems you can try this one: `^[[:space:]]*\\(?(020[78]?\\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2,3} ?[0-9]{4}|0[1-8][0-9]{3}\\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{3})[[:space:]]*$`

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are using has at least 2 issues: 1) the escapes should be doubled, and 2) there are 2 groups separated with `|` that makes the `^` and `$` apply to the two branches separately.

```
'^\s*\(?(020[78]?\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2,3} ?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8][0-9]{3}\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{3})\s*$'
        ^--------------------------------------^ ^------------------------------------------^
```

You can use

```
'^[[:space:]]*\\(?(020[78]?\\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2,3} ?[0-9]{4}|0[1-8][0-9]{3}\\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{3})[[:space:]]*$'
```

Breakdown:

- `^` - start of string
- `[[:space:]]*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\\(?` - 1 or 0 `(` chars
- `(020[78]?\\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2,3} ?[0-9]{4}|0[1-8][0-9]{3}\\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{3})` - An alternation group matching 2 alternatives:

  - `020[78]?\\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2,3} ?[0-9]{4}` - `020` + optional `7` or `8` +  an optional `)` + an optional space + a digit from `1` to `9` + 3 or 2 digits + an optional space + 4 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `0[1-8][0-9]{3}\\)? ?[1-9][0-9]{2} ?[0-9]{3}` - `0` + a digit from `1` to `8` + 3 digits + an optional `)` +  an optional space + a digit from `1` to `9` + 2 digits + an optional space + 3 digits
- `[[:space:]]*`  - 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Is that working the way you expect? If not, please provide more test cases.